# Xcode 8.3.1 - Compiler can no longer handle circular references?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, llvm, circular-reference

I have been developing a C++ game engine for a long time. I have never had any issues with the compiler, or anything like that, until I update to Xcode 8.3.1!

Suddenly, it appears that a default setting was changed when I updated that made it so that the compiler simply cannot handle circular references.

Does anyone know how to set this back, (I tried downgrading Xcode, and it still doesn't work!)

My circular referencing looks something like this:

- I have a class called "Object" defined in my code
- "Object" includes another class called "Renderer2D"
- "Renderer2D" includes another class called "Renderable2D"
- "Renderable2D" extends "Object"

My "Object" class:

```
#pragma once

#include "Graphics/2D/Renderer2D.h"

namespace kineticengine {

    class Object {
    public:
        Object();
        virtual ~Object() {}

        virtual void render(graphics::Renderer2D* renderer) const;
    };

}
```

My "Renderer2D" class:

```
#pragma once

#include "Renderable2D.h"

namespace kineticengine {
    namespace graphics {

        class Renderer2D {
        protected:
            Renderer2D() {}
        public:
            virtual void submit(const Renderable2D* renderable) {}; // Error here, "Unknown type name 'Renderable2D', did you mean 'Renderer2D'?"
        };

    }
}
```

My "Renderable2D" class:

```
#pragma once

#include "Renderer2D.h"    
#include "../../Object.h"

namespace kineticengine {
    namespace graphics {
        class Renderable2D : public Object {
        public:
            Renderable2D() : Object() {}

            virtual ~Renderable2D() {}

            void render(Renderer2D* renderer) const override {
                renderer->submit(this); // Error here "Cannot initialize parameter of type 'const kineticengine::graphics::Renderer2D *' with an rvalue of type 'const kineticengine::graphics::Renderable2D *'"
            }
        };

    }
}
```

All of my errors are basically variations of "Unknown class [x]" where x is one of the other classes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's somewhat hard to comment without seeing a [representative test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Please add some *actual* code, along with the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: While trying to reproduce this, I'm having to make too many changes. Can you reduce the problem further?

Comment: I minified the code to only the stuff you would need to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renderable2D.h is including Renderer2D.h before defining class Renderable2D, so when Renderer2D.h refers to class Renderable2D, it is not yet defined. Clang is behaving correctly.

One way to break this cycle is to not include headers if you're only going to refer to a class by pointer or reference. You then put a forward declaration for the class in instead of the include directive. This has the added bonus of speeding up compile time as well.

Comment: What I just don't get is why clang was compiling with 0 errors and 0 warnings before, and now it's all messed up!